# Send parameter into custom GitHub action

Tags: github, github-actions

**What specific syntax must be changed in the code below in order to successfully pass a parameter into the GitHub custom action from the GitHub workflow?**

The workflow file code is at `.github/workflows/mycustomworkflow.yml` and contains the code:

```
name: send-param-into-custom-action
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  send-the-param:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: SendParamIntoCustomAction
        uses: ./.github/actions/my-custom-action
        with:
          custom_param: "Some literal string"
```

The GitHub action file is at `.github/actions/my-custom-action/action.yml` and contains the code:

```
name: 'Pass a parameter into a custom action'
description: 'Receives a parameter and prints it out.'
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - shell: bash
      name: Print the parameter value
      env:
        custom_param: ${{ inputs.custom_param }}
      run: |
        echo 'About to echo the parameter value'
        echo $custom_param
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an [`inputs` object](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#inputs) in the metadata file:

```yaml
name: Pass a parameter into a custom action
description: Receives a parameter and prints it out.

inputs:
  custom_param:
    description: Custom input parameter
    required: true

runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - shell: bash
      name: Print the parameter value
      env:
        custom_param: ${{ inputs.custom_param }}
      run: |
        echo 'About to echo the parameter value'
        echo "$custom_param"
```

Comment: What if I want to pass something from the workflow into the actions? Is this possible?
Like
        env:
          ENV: 'feature'
        uses: ./.github/actions/allure
I need the ENV to be accessible in the custom action as an input.  is that possible?

Comment: @user875531 Environment variables are available in the environment of the action being executed, but if you want to pass them in explicitly, you can access them from the `env` context. You could have an input parameter and set its value accordingly: `custom_param: ${{ env.VARIABLE }}`

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example showcasing passing of parameters.

name:  Build & deploy iOS & Android app

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
       package-name:
        required: true
        type: string
       package-path:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  build_android_package:
    name:  Build for android
    uses: ./.github/workflows/_android_app_build.yml
    with:
      package-name: ${{inputs.package-name}}
      package-path: ${{inputs.package-path}}
```

Above is a reusable githubaction / workflow which is invoked `on: workflow_call` which means it will be invoked by other workflow. Such workflows are defined in a file starting with _ for e.g.

```
_deploy_apps_on_env.yml
```

And now this will be called by below

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_apps_for_dev_env:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/_deploy_apps_on_env.yml
needs: [ 'test' ]
with:
  package-name: app-dev-release.apk
  package-path: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk
```

Here we are calling the reusable workflow and passing two parameters which are required by the workflow.